# Vagrant up does not work in macos m2 pro with lates ventura

Tags: macos, vagrant, macos-ventura

I have installed vagrant, wmvare fusion in macos m2. But when I run vagrant up it returns below error:

> An error occurred while executing vmrun, a utility for controlling VMware machines. The command and output are below:
> Command: ["-T", "player", "list", {:notify=>[:stdout, :stderr]}]
> Stdout: Invalid host type 'player' specified Error: The operation is not supported
> Stderr:

How can I solve this problem ?

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "bytesguy/ubuntu-server-20.04-arm64"
    config.vm.box_version = "1.0.0"
    config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
    config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)"
    config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |vmware|
      vmware.gui = true
      vmware.cpus = 2
      vmware.vmx["ethernet0.virtualdev"] = "vmxnet3"
      vmware.ssh_info_public = true
      vmware.linked_clone = false
      vmware.allowlist_verified = true
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install vagrant-vmware-desktop veresion 3.0.1 instead of 3.0.2:

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-desktop
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop --plugin-version 3.0.1
```

See: https://superuser.com/a/1783236/79465