# Invalid host type 'player' specified

Tags: macos, vagrant

I have the same error. I noticed the "vmrun -T player ...." doesn't work but "vmrun -T fusion" does. Though I still don't know how to execute -T fusion instead of -T player within vagrant. Any help ?

Comment: What kind of VM is it and where did you get it? What's its file-name?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error when using `vagrant-vmware-desktop` version `3.0.2`. Reverting to `3.0.1` seems to fix the issue

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-desktop
vagrant plugin install --plugin-version=3.0.1 vagrant-vmware-desktop
```